# I can get search results from xelement query into listbox but not from listbox to xaml file

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, xaml, listbox

I am writing a windows phone 7 app and i have an xml file which looks like this

```
    <Barcodes>
  <Barcode code="7393997155338"
           companyName="Garbo Food AB"
           productName="Toast Loaf"/>

</Barcodes>
```

I am searching the xml file using xElement like below, i am getting not null on the listbox which says to me its populated?!?

```
        var searchElement = XElement.Load("storedBarcodes.xml");
        var barcodeProductResult = from var in searchElement.Descendants("Barcodes") 
                                   where var.Attribute("code").Value == b
                                   select new ProductBarcodes()
                                   {
                                       code = var.Attribute("code").Value,
                                       companyName = var.Attribute("companyName").Value,
                                       productName = var.Attribute("productName").Value

                                   };
        if (barcodeProductResult != null)
        {
            tbSuccessfullSearchOrNot.Text = ("Search has found a matching product!");

            if (resultsListBox != null)
            {

                resultsListBox.ItemsSource = barcodeProductResult;
                tbSuccessfullSearchOrNot.Text = ("Search has found a matching product! but listbox is not empty");
            }
            else
            {

                tbSuccessfullSearchOrNot.Text = ("Search has found a matching product! but listbox is empty");
            }
                //tbProductBarcode.Text = ("Product Barcode : " + _code + Environment.NewLine);
            //tbCompanyName.Text = ("Company Name: " + _companyName + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        else
        {
            tbSuccessfullSearchOrNot.Text = ("No matching product found!");
        }
```

and after the listbox is populated it should be output on the screen like below, I am trying a couple of ways ie. using {Binding Path=Element[code].Value}", and just Text="{Binding code}, the result is empty on output screen,

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Height="150" Content="Press here to scan a barcode !!" Click="Button_Click" Foreground="#FF2FFF07" />
        <TextBlock Margin="30" FontSize="36" TextWrapping="Wrap"   x:Name="tbSuccessfullSearchOrNot"/>
        <TextBlock Margin="30" FontSize="36" TextWrapping="Wrap"   x:Name="tbScanResultBarCode"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="resultsListBox" TabIndex="8" ItemsSource="barcodeProductResult" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="10" >
                        <TextBlock x:Name="results" Text="{Binding code}"   FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Orange"  />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Element[code].Value}" Foreground="Black"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding companyName}" Foreground="Black"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding productName}" Foreground="Black"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <!--<TextBlock Height="346" FontSize="36" x:Name="tbProductDetails" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Width="450" >

        </TextBlock>-->
        <TextBox Height="71" Name="tbProductBarcode"  Width="460" IsEnabled="False" IsReadOnly="True" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=tbProductBarcode}" />
        <TextBox Height="71" Name="tbCompanyName"  Width="460" IsEnabled="False" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <TextBox Height="71" Name="tbProductName"  Width="460" IsEnabled="False" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <!--<Button Height="150" Content="Tap to scan a QR code" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        <TextBlock Margin="30" FontSize="36" TextWrapping="Wrap" x:Name="tbScanResultQR"/>-->

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Post Edit:
This is the code im basing my search on. This works,

```
       private void menuBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = XElement.Load("SearchFile.xml");
        var filteredData = from var in element.Descendants("chipper")
                           where var.Attribute("County").Value.ToLower()==tbSearch.Text.ToLower() 
                           select new Counties()
                           {
                               LName = var.Attribute("LName").Value,
                               PlAddress = var.Attribute("PlAddress").Value,
                               County= var.Attribute("County").Value,
                               PhoneNumber = var.Attribute("PhoneNumber").Value


                           };

        ChipperListBox.ItemsSource = filteredData;
    }
```

and the xaml:

```
  <StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,90" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ListBox x:Name="ChipperListBox" SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="10" >
                    <TextBlock x:Name="chipName" Text="{Binding LName}"   FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Orange" Tap="chipName_Tap" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PlAddress}" Foreground="Black"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding County}" Foreground="Black"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PhoneNumber}" Foreground="Black"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

EDIT: I un this app on a windows phone because the emulator has no camera.heres the info from call stack after changing the element name to "Barcode" i get a readerException which stops the barcode scanner almost instantly but when i stop debugging i run again outside visual studio just on the phone and the app runs but still no output to the listbox in the xaml

> "A first chance exception of type 'com.google.zxing.ReaderException'
>   occurred in Silverlight_ZXing_Core.dll
>
> Additional information: ReaderException"

```
Silverlight_ZXing_Core.dll!com.google.zxing.oned.UPCEANReader.findGuardPattern(com.google.zxing.common.BitArray row, int rowOffset, bool whiteFirst, int[] pattern) + 0xf1 bytes    
    Silverlight_ZXing_Core.dll!com.google.zxing.oned.UPCEANReader.findStartGuardPattern(com.google.zxing.common.BitArray row) + 0x8 bytes   
    Silverlight_ZXing_Core.dll!com.google.zxing.oned.UPCEANReader.decodeRow(int rowNumber, com.google.zxing.common.BitArray row, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<object,object> hints)    
    Silverlight_ZXing_Core.dll!com.google.zxing.oned.OneDReader.doDecode(com.google.zxing.BinaryBitmap image, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<object,object> hints) + 0x113 bytes 
    Silverlight_ZXing_Core.dll!com.google.zxing.oned.OneDReader.decode(com.google.zxing.BinaryBitmap image, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<object,object> hints) 
    Silverlight_ZXing_Core.dll!com.google.zxing.oned.OneDReader.decode(com.google.zxing.BinaryBitmap image) + 0x3 bytes 
>   WP7.ScanBarCode.dll!WP7.ScanBarCode.BarCode.cam_AutoFocusCompleted(object sender, Microsoft.Devices.CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 114 + 0x7 bytes   C#
    Microsoft.Phone.dll!Microsoft.Devices.Camera.SafeFireEvent<Microsoft.Devices.CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs>.AnonymousMethod__1f(object ignored) + 0x17 bytes    
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.WaitCallback_Context(object state) + 0x18 bytes   
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x63 bytes    
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(object o) + 0x47 bytes 
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Timer.ring() + 0x70 bytes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Barcodes` is your root element and you want a list of `Barcode` items, so use this as your `from`:

```
from barcode in searchElement.Descendants("Barcode")
```

As a side note, your null checks aren't correct. `barcodeProductResult` will not be null, but it might have a `Count()` of 0. `resultsListBox` will also never be null.

Comment: "Use this as your from:
from element in searchElement.Descendants("Barcode")" <- should i use "Barcode" instead of "Barcodes"?

Comment: ty for side note i have changed to look at how many elements are in the list if (resultsListBox.Items.Count() == 0)

Comment: I edited to use "Barcode" element instead of "Barcode" but this results in the app crashing? i have coomented out the if tests and just use "resultsListBox.ItemsSource = barcodeProductResult;" after the  "productName = barcode.Attribute("productName").Value
  };"

Comment: You also need to do what @L.B says and call ToList() on your barcodeProductResult.

Comment: where should i call toList() on barcodeProductResult after the select method. also is this what you mean resultsListBox.ItemsSource = barcodeProductResult.ToList();

Comment: Im sure i dont need to call ToList, question still open, im trying to get data from xml file to listbox which is made in .xaml

Comment: Can you post the details of the crash you saw after you fixed the linq? Exception message and stack trace.

Comment: It looks like your barcode scanning library is crashing. I'm not sure how that could relate to your list binding but I'd suggest breaking your program up into smaller pieces so you can test each part. Use the Visual Studio debugger to step through and see where the exception is raised. Good luck.

Comment: ty mafue im not too worried about the reader exception because once the app is installed it doesnt occur. In the method where i search the xml i put a try/catch surrounding from the start "var searchElement = XElement.Load("storedBarcodes.xml");" to "resultsListBox.ItemsSource = barcodeProductResult;"  and when i done this it went to catch so theres defo something going wrong within. Ty for your help mafue :)

Comment: ty mafue foir the help with the barcode element... as it tourned out i had a space in an attribute name in the xml whiuch crashed the app. all working now thx